# How to check what <input> tag says for a password

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a sign-in page for my website and I wanted to make a `input` for my password system.

I've used the prompt() solution but it is not very efficient.

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password.."/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
```

I know that I don't have any Javascript set up, which I'm expecting to use for this. I have a little knowledge of Javascript, not very much though. I couldn't find anything online as to the answer.

Comment: no clue what you are asking. Are you asking how to read the value of an input?

Comment: yes, i didn't know how to explain it

Comment: so add event listener to detect click, select the input, read the value. Plenty of online tutorials.

Comment: I dont know what any of that means, im very new to this..

Comment: LEARN.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript

Comment: sorry? i didnt understand.

Comment: Sorry Simon, but this platform **is not** the starting point you are looking for. You'll have to do what any other person has to do as well, when they start with a new technology: Learn. Do research. Give things a try. And then, when you have an idea of what you are doing, and things just won't work, show the code you have tried here, describe how it fails, what is expected instead, and you'll be helped in no time.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: yes, thank you Reza Ghorbani. I need to find a way to check the value of both the password input and the username input to check if they are equal to a certain value i put in, i know this isnt the safest way to do it, i just want to know how to

Comment: This a not a place of Tutorials. Learn first when you faced any problem come back. This community will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also wanted to make login page.

1) For the input I want to trigger an event function to check if password is right so I say

```
<input type = "password" id = "passwordInput"></input>
<button onclick = "myfunction()">Submit</button>
```

2) Now that I have the onclick, I need to make my function

```
    function myfunction() {
        var pass = document.getElementById("passwordInput"); 

        //this returns the value of input
    }
```

3) I now need to check if the password is right so I add this to myfunction()

```
    if(pass.value == "correct password") {
       alert("You have logged successfully")
    }
```

One good website to find out how to make a login page is 
https://getcodingkids.com/code-skill/create-a-password/

Comment: thank you but.. it doesnt let me do .value .... i dont know why

Comment: i added a good website that you should check out to help you and also editing value code, did this help?

Comment: ive got it! you have to declare the variable and then check the value? its weird, ill send a snippit

Comment: ```function checkpassword() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var pass = password.value;
  if(pass == "admin"){
     alert("Correct!");
  }
}
```

Comment: check out this website https://getcodingkids.com/code-skill/create-a-password/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function checkpassword() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var pass = password.value;
  if(pass == "admin"){
     alert("Correct!");
  }
}
<script>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<button onclick="return checkpassword()">Login</button>
```

Comment: Done sorry for not doing that earlier

Answer (score 0):

Use basic if statements.

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password.."/>
<input type="button" value="Login" name="login" onclick="checkPass(document.getElementById('password').value)"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function checkPass(pass){
    if(pass == "correct pass"){
        alert("Access Granted");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please check your password");
    }
}
```