# What is the difference when using Javascript's .value?

Tags: javascript

**Example**:

```
var a = document.getElementById("my-input").value;
```

Or

```
var a = document.getElementById("my-input");
var b = a.value;
```

Sometimes, when I use the former, (like when I answered a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574773/how-to-check-what-input-tag-says-for-a-password/58575938#58575938)), it does not work when used in conditional statements, and I had to use the latter to get the solution to work.

**Question**

Why did, in the question I answered, did Simon, say

```
var pass = document.getElementById("passwordInput"); 
if(pass.value == "correct password") {
console.log("hi");
}
```

did not work for him?
And instead he had to use

```
function checkpassword() { 
    var password = document.getElementById("password"); 
    var pass = password.value;
    if(pass == "admin"){ 
       alert("Correct!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It depends on if you are going to use the element for anything else.

Comment: If you want to use the element later, do the second. If you only need its `value`, use the first.

Comment: `a` is an object while `b` is an immutable. If you evaluate `a` several times, you can get different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `document.getElementById("my-input")` for something else, put it in a separate variable. If you will only ever need the `.value`, your first option is fine. There's no point in separating it out if you're not going to utilise that separation.

Comment: There can be a point to separating it out, even if you're not going to use a value more than once, if you use descriptive variable names. In such cases, the variable name itself can add clarity when reading the code and help document why you are obtaining a value. It can also help to split long sequences into more manageable conceptual chunks. OTOH, I agree that just using a variable name like `a` or `b` doesn't provide much, if any, benefit when you're not going to use the value more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use you need to make of them.

If you use two distinct variables:

```
const a = document.getElementById("my-input");
const b = a.value;
```

The only thing you need to know is that the variable a can change its status through an event at the UI, while the variable b remains unchanged.